# Opening a new CMD window within a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I swear this assignment will be the end of me, I've been researching this new problem for the greater part of the day and getting quite stuck. The problem is as follows: we've been tasked with finding a command that will open a new cmd window and change the color (both foreground and background), AND the prompt. The lecturer specified the use of the 'cmd' command however: I can't find the switches (if that's the correct term) or parameters to use. I did find that--

```
START COLOR A4
```

did the correct sort of thing, however this is using the incorrect command and when trying to add a second parameter:

```
START COLOR A4 PROMPT $V
```

It did not work correctly. This may partly be due to my lack of knowledge on the use of delimiters and how to send in multiple parameters to a command.

Thanks in advance for the help. JohnW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of hints should sort you out:

```
START COLOR A4
```

is shorthand for

```
START cmd /k "COLOR A4"
```

See [the syntax for cmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771320%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and pay special attention to the Remarks section - it tells you how to issue multiple commands.

Comment: THANKS! `START cmd /k "COLOR A4&&PROMPT $V"` worked great! One more question, is there a way to keep the original instance of CMD in focus?

Comment: I think only by starting the new window minimized.

Comment: Thanks again, the second question wasn't that important, you've helped a bunch.